# JQuery: bind keyboard to function event

Tags: jquery, keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard-events

How can detect the keyboard  key down and trigger this line?

`$('#submit_p').live('click',function(event){...}`

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$(document).keydown(function()){

           if(event.keyCode == 37){  //prev key

                  }else if(event.keyCode == 39){  //next key

                  }else if(event.keyCode == 13){  //enter key
                      $('#submit_p').live('click',function(event){...}  
                  }if(event.keyCode == 27){  //escape key

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. But how di I assign the <Enter> key?

Comment: Edited the answer (i left other keys so you can see more examples, you can just remove others and leave 13 code = ENTER). Happy coding